# VBA delete rows when cell in column A contains (partially) certain value, for the entire workbook

Tags: excel, vba, rowdeleting

I'm trying to delete rows when the first column contains a certain value "viz" (for example viz.Heeft.u.geholpen).

I got this working for one sheet, but i want to do this for all sheets at the same time. I'm quite new in VBA, and tried multiple example codes, combining them but none of it worked out well.

deleting rows within a sheet,

```
Sub tekst_verwijderen()
With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With Range("a1", Range("a" & rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 1, "viz*"
        On Error Resume Next
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Sub
```

But i have no clue how i can edit the code so it runs it for all sheets within the workbook

Comment: First put a `.` in front of every instance of `Range` and `Rows`.

Comment: Then add an outer loop: `Dim ws As Worksheet`, `For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`, ... `Next`. And change `With ActiveSheet` to `With ws`.

Comment: to extend, is is possible to add more criteria? I tried adding another via 'criteria2:' but i get an error

Comment: Sure. There are lots of similar questions here on SO about `AutoFilter` with multiple criteria. There is also the [`Range.AutoFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) documentation.

Comment: Welcome bas! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!